# KendoUI Grid filter redirecting to another page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Something very strange is happening when I am using the filter of KendoUI Grid. My grid is very simple and the definition is like this:

> ```
>     var cols = [];
>
>     cols[0] = { field: 'name', title: 'Nome', width: "65%" };
>     cols[1] = { field: 'eMail', title: 'eMail', width: "20%" };
>     cols[2] = { field: 'city', title: 'Cidade', width: "15%" };
>
>     var cfgGrid = { dataSource: dsPersons, 
>                     batch: false, 
>                     change: onSelectedRow,
>                     selectable: "row", 
>                     resizable: true, 
>                     scrollable: true, 
>                     sortable: { mode: 'multiple', allowUnsort: true }, 
>                     filterable: true, 
>                     editable: false, 
>                     pageable: { numeric: false }, 
>                     columns: cols };
>
>     gridPessoas = null;
>     gridPessoas = $("#gridElem").kendoGrid(cfgGrid).data("kendoGrid");
> ```

The grid is displayed correctly in url:

> http://myLocalhost.com:50409/#/personsView

But when I try to filter any column kendoUI redirects to a page:

> http://myLocalhost.com:50409/undefined?

The grid is ok and the error only occurs when I define a filter value and click on the filter button.

This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 site. I cannot imagine what is going on.

Can you help me ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you define the `DataSource` `dsPersons`? There is one option in the `DataSource` that is [`serverFiltering`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#serverfiltering-booleandefault) that if true then `transport.read` is used for retrieving the new (filtered) data.

Comment: No, but I have defined serverFiltering as false, and it did worked too

Comment: var dsPersons = { data: persons, 
                   schema: model, 
                   filter: {}, 
                   serverPaging: false,
                   serverFiltering: false, 
                   pageSize: 12 };

Comment: I've basically copied your code to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/cjmb9/1/) and it works fine. Please, check if it works for you and what is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered the problem.

I am working with Sammy that is a javascript framework that allows us to define routes and each time a new location is defined Sammy set window.location to the new location.

I have just started to work with Sammy so I cannot give you more details. But when I select a  KendoUI filter the "setLocation" Method of Sammy is called with a new location equal to "undefined?".

I do not know why is KendoUI causing this kind of behaviour but this is the real problem.

Comment: Same problem here. Do you have any news/fixes to that? Thanks for posting all this online.